# not able to invoke/query chaincode usin fabric Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have created a sample HLF network with 3 organizations. I have taken an orderer and a peer from each organization ( **total 3 orderers, 3 peers, 3 fabric-CA, 3 CouchDB instances**).

I have successfully created the certificates, system channel, channel configuration, application channel and also successfully deployed the chaincode on each peer.
I am able to invoke/query any chaincode using **peer binary** in docker cli **but not able to invoke/query the same chaincode through fabric Node SDK.**

I have created the connection profile as per the template provided in the test network and also able to register any user for a specific organization. But whenever I am trying to query any chaincode function I am getting the below error:

> [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on
> Committer- name: orderer.example.com:7050, url:grpcs://localhost:7050,
> connected:false, connectAttempted:true [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady
>
> - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer.example.com:7050 url:grpcs://localhost:7050 timeout:3000

When I check the orderer logs I found this error:

> ServerHandshake -> ERRO 087 Server TLS handshake failed in 2.085859ms
> with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.23.0.1:45678

****Why I am getting this error?**

**I am trying to just query so why it's connecting to the orderer?**

**If there is any TLS issue then why I am able to query it through peer binary?****

Answer (score 0):

This link might help [Hyperledger Fabric CA releasing wrong certificates (wrong issuer) to Node SDK when TLS enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375689/hyperledger-fabric-ca-releasing-wrong-certificates-wrong-issuer-to-node-sdk-wh)

If you are not running as a test network on your local machine, then you will need to specify the connection option of discovery.asLocalhost as false

Comment: I am running this network on my local machine and I have set discovery.asLocalhost as true. I tried few options but nothing worked.